# Adapt a view if an app is installed with Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-apps

I have a web app with a project that works alone (it's index, login.. pages).

I would need to change the index page if a new app is installed (e.g: add a link, a table in the template with my app models..). Have it dynamic.

The removal of the app must let the project intact and just remove the link.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def my_view(request):
    from django.conf import settings
    app_installed = 'app_name' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS

    return render_to_response(template_name, {'app_installed': app_installed})
```

template:

```
{% if app_installed %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This will fail if the application was enabled using an application configuration class. It's better to [use the application registry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43189917/244297).

Comment: The docs say _Your code should never access `INSTALLED_APPS` directly. Use `django.apps.apps` instead._ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 16):

You can use the Django's [application registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/):

```
In [1]: from django.apps import apps
In [2]: apps.is_installed("django.contrib.admin")
Out[2]: True
```

An application can actually be [enabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) by using a dotted Python path to either its package or the application's configuration class (preferred). Simply checking if `"app_name"` is in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` will fail in the latter case.

Answer (score 5):

Or use a custom context processor.

In `installed_apps.py`

```
from django.conf import settings

def installed_apps(request):
    return {
       'app_installed' : 'app_name' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
    }
```

In `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'installed_apps.installed_apps'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`simple_tag` version:

The tricky part is that *you can't pass arguments* to your `simple_tag` when it's used in a conditional.  Therefor, you create a new variable specifically for your installed app with `as is_myapp_installed`.

In `templatetags/my_filters.py`:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def is_app_installed(app):
  from django.apps import apps
  return apps.is_installed(app)
```

In template:

```
{% load my_filters %}
   ...
{% is_app_installed "myapp" as is_myapp_installed %}    
{% if is_myapp_installed %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```